# Сброс изменений при выходе из функции php

Tags: php, функции

Нужно написать функцию которая добавляет объект в массив. В данном случае это
AddNewOffer().

```
class OfferManager
{
    var $offers = array();

    public function Creator()
    {
        return new Offer(0, 'asd', 'asd', 'asd');
    }

    public function AddNewOffer($offers, $of)
    {
        array_push($offers, $of);
        print_r($offers);
    }

    public function Printer($offers)
    {
        print_r($offers);
    }
}
```

Код вызова:

```
$_OfferManager = new OfferManager();
$of;
$of = $_OfferManager->Creator();

$_OfferManager->AddNewOffer($_OfferManager->offers, $of);
echo '</br>';
$_OfferManager->printer($_OfferManager->offers);
```

Вывод:

```
Array ( [0] => Offer Object ( [id] => 0 [dealer] => asd [model] => asd [cost] => asd ) )
Array ( )
```

Обратите внимание, что при вызове print_r() c другой функции выводит пустой массив, можно сделать заключение, что изменения внутри функции AddNewOffer() происходят локально и исчезнуть после выхода из функции.

Господа, есть ли способ выполнить изменения глобально, чтобы они не пропадали после выхода из своей функции? Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае тело метода `AddNewOffer` должно быть таким:

```
public function AddNewOffer($of)
{
   $this->offers[] = $of; // формат вызова, рекомендованый пользователем @And
   print_r($this->offers);
}
```

И вызов таким:

```
$_OfferManager->AddNewOffer($of);
```

В изначальном коде вы задаёте значение для локальной переменной, доступной внутри метода. Используя `$this->offers` вы записиваете офферы в атрибут класса.

Comment: спасибо, я также понял что еще можно выполнить передачу по ссылке с помощью символа &, тогда запись пойдет в главный массив а не копию

Comment: Внёс изменения в ответ, теперь параметр $offers не нужен на входе функции

Comment: Лучше заменить `array_push` на `$this->offers[]=$of;`, да и работать будет шустрее.

Comment: Да,  так посимпатичнее)